# Excel, auto refresh consolidation statistics

Tags: excel, consolidation

What if I have list of activities and every day I fix how many hours were spent reading, writing, etc.

And I want to see summary by Date field, for example 17 July I was walking for 4 hours and reading for 7 (total is **11**):

[image]

I added consolidation by left column, like described in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IGaq_biQ1B8

But how to make this statistics aut-updating(later I'll add other records but statistics ends for 20 July)?

Comment: What do you mean? You want to know how to have your column G auto-update when a value in "Hours" changes?  Say you change the walking on 17 July to 6 hours. You want the "Total Hours" for that day to update?

Comment: Use a pivot table.

Comment: Hi! Sorry english not native. No, mean if I add new records for example for "23-July-17", I want to see new consolidation records too (now as I understand - I need to recalculate it every time for new rows..)
http://imgur.com/a/ma2rn

Comment: The dynamic version is a bit complicated with array formula https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-unique-items-from-a-list, and SUMPRODUCT to get the sum of each item. VBA Macro to refresh the Pivot Table on Worksheet Change event can be easier http://www.eonesolutions.com/blog-post/tech-tues-automatically-refreshing-pivot-tables-excel-refreshable-reports/

Comment: Thank You @Slai!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so as I understand I can create a Pivot Table near. It does not recalculate values "on-the-fly", but I can press "Refresh all" on the ribbon and data is renewed:

[image]